# Outlook app-level modifications, establishing connection between widget and Outlook on-click

Tags: widget, hololens, outlook-api, outlook-graph-api

I am working on creating an email widget to display it on home-screen of Hololens. I am using Outlook API and Unity to do this.

On clicking any of the emails on widget, it should open the same email in Outlook App. Could you guys help me with the steps on how to achieve this.

Thanks on advance